# Using sets of variables to create another set of variables, or why not?

Tags: r, for-loop, dynamic-variables

My dataset contains variables that measure the same thing at 5 different points. Let's call them X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 and Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5. This is just how the dataset is set up. I'm importing it as a data.table. I'd like to make another variable off of these: Z1 = X1 * c + Y1.

I've read that you should not loop to create dynamic variables. So here are my series of questions:

(a) Why should I not loop? I'd like to have the variables in the data.table so that they can be run in a regression and I don't have to specify each element of the list separately. These seem like I should loop to create Z1-Z5, no? I'm trying to understand the benefit of a list instead of a loop, especially here where I already have numbered variables.

(b) What's the most efficient way to create these variables? Whether that's into a list or through a loop. Since I already have to loop through X1-X5 and Y1-Y5, I'm already doing the "ill-advised" loop, right?

Answer (score 1):

In general working with data that includes values in the column names is more difficult than working with data that includes only one column per measurement. To make this more concrete, your current arrangement looks like this:

```
exd <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5*5*2),
                         nrow = 5,
                         dimnames = list(1:5, c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5",
                                                 "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4", "Y5"))))
```

A more reasonable arrangement like this

```
library(tidyr)
exd <- data.frame(id = 1:nrow(exd), exd)
exd <- gather(exd, "variable", "value", -id)
exd <- separate(exd, variable, into = c("variable", "time"), sep = 1)
exd <- spread(exd, variable, value)
```

makes the data much easier to manipulate. For example, you can create `Z` like this:

```
exd <- transform(exd, Z = X * 10 + Y)
exd
##    id time           X          Y           Z
## 1   1    1 -0.60189285  0.5500440  -5.4688845
## 2   1    2 -0.09514745  0.6053707  -0.3461038
## 3   1    3 -0.09736927  0.8009143  -0.1727783
## 4   1    4 -0.73479925 -0.2732481  -7.6212406
## 5   1    5  0.96726726  0.8641525  10.5368251
## 6   2    1 -0.99369859  1.2366758  -8.7003101
## 7   2    2 -0.89594782 -0.5063335  -9.4658118
## 8   2    3  0.21615254  1.1652534   3.3267788
## 9   2    4 -0.13180279 -0.4686998  -1.7867277
## 10  2    5 -0.10828009 -1.1986224  -2.2814233
## 11  3    1  1.02678506  0.1390979  10.4069484
## 12  3    2 -2.07075107 -1.4205655 -22.1280762
## 13  3    3  0.88246516  0.3588557   9.1835074
## 14  3    4  0.31001699  0.7041673   3.8043371
## 15  3    5 -0.69842067  0.6394920  -6.3447147
## 16  4    1  0.75106130  0.4102751   7.9208881
## 17  4    2  0.15012013  0.1279930   1.6291943
## 18  4    3  0.20559750 -0.6085572   1.4474179
## 19  4    4 -1.03968035 -1.1973635 -11.5941670
## 20  4    5 -0.27594517  2.4302267  -0.3292250
## 21  5    1 -1.50916654 -0.5584569 -15.6501223
## 22  5    2 -0.07921171  1.9458512   1.1537341
## 23  5    3 -0.61643584 -0.2022409  -6.3665993
## 24  5    4 -0.18430887  0.8663661  -0.9767226
## 25  5    5  1.11464855 -0.5572155  10.5892700
```

no loops required!

Comment: Thanks Ista. So basically what you're saying is that I should convert the dataset from wide to long, and that this is better because it's just easier to manipulate. And then, I suppose, I would convert it back into a wide dataset when I was running a regression. I guess I don't see what this is necessarily better than just creating Z1-Z5, instead of a multi-step process to convert into a long, manipulate, then back to a wide.

Comment: I'm saying that you should keep your data in long form as a general rule, converting to wide only when needed.